# Permitir que uma function seja chamado só depois de um tempo que pagina foi carrega

Tags: javascript, html

gostaria de saber se há um modo de permitir que uma function seja chamado só depois de alguns segundos. Exemplo tenho uma função que emite som quando surgi uma nova mensagem ela e chamada, mas quando eu reinicio a página a function é chamada logo de inicio, a notificação deve ficar mais o som não deve ser chamado, somente quando chega uma mensagem ai sim deve ser chamado.

Assim, vamos dizer que você recebeu uma msg e não vai ler agora, mas toda vez que aquela msg for maior que 1 ele chama a função emitirSom(), mas quero que só chame esta function quando o ajax ficar trabalhando, mas ele volta com as notificações(até ai tudo bem), e chama a function som, ou seja toda vez que troca de pagina a mesma chama a função que acaba irritando.

Código:

Função ajax:

```
function notificarNMsg(id, tp_usuario, codigo, ultimos_id) {
    ids = ultimos_id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pages/atualizacoes.php', /* URL que será chamada */
        type: 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
        data: {ANLid_usuario: id, ANLtp_usuario: tp_usuario, ANLcodigo: codigo, ultimos_id: ids},
        dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.msg_nao_lidas >= 0) {
                if (data.ids == 0) {
                    $("#areaMsg").html('<span></span>').removeClass("vibrarMsg");
                } else if (data.ids !== 0 && data.msg_nao_lidas > 0) {
                    qtd_existente = $("#areaMsg  span").text();
                    if (qtd_existente == '') {
                        qtd_existente = 0;
                    }
                    qtd_msg_total = parseInt(qtd_existente) + parseInt(data.msg_nao_lidas);
                    $("#areaMsg").html('<span>' + qtd_msg_total + '</span>').addClass("vibrarMsg");
                    acionarAlerta('./sons/nv_msg.wav');
                    trocarTituloPorTempo('- (' + qtd_msg_total + ') Mensagem');
                    if (ids != 0) {
                        ids = ids + ',' + data.ids.join(",");
                    } else {
                        ids = data.ids.join(",");
                    }
                }
            }
            notificarNMsg(id, tp_usuario, codigo, ids);
        }
    });
}
```

Function que deveria ser "Criada" após alguns segundos.

```
function acionarAlerta(caminho) {
    var som = new Audio(caminho);
    som.play();
}
```

Comment: Veja mais sobre setTimeout(), algo como: `setTimeout(function(){alert("minha msg")}, 500)`, a função será chamada assim que der o tempo(500, em ms). Veja mais: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Sim disso eu sei, mas não é bem isso, tipo no começo uma function chama outra function que emite som, só que ela está programada pra não ser chamado até ser passar uns 30 segs.

Comment: Podes explicar a pergunta melhor? está pouco clara...

Comment: Tentei... vê ai.

Comment: Coloca o código da function e de como você a chama, assim o pessoal consegue te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Pronto! acho que agora ficou melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Aguarde o evento `DOMContentLoaded` do documento - este indicará que a página foi finalizada. Após isso, você pode implementar um TimeOut a ser executado após N milissegundos.

```
// Aguarde a finalização da carga da página:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    // Dispare um evento daqui a 5 segundos (5000 milissegundos):
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        // Redirecionando...
        location.href = "https://www.google.com.br";
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Mas eu não quero redirecionar, o que eu quero é que emite o som somente quando o usuário estiver coma a pagina aberta, não quando ele atualiza a pagina com as novas msgs nao lidas.

Comment: @RomarioPires este é apenas um exemplo de implementação. Sinta-se à vontade para alterar o código e realizar suas chamadas.

Comment: Ok, mas assim eu não quero que o javascript chame, somente o ajax, Entendeu? Tipo o Ajax chama quando carregar a pagina mas a function não existe, ela só é criada depois de 5 segs, ai dps desse tempo o ajax chama de novo, ai sim o acionarAlerta funciona!

Comment: @RomarioPires a função anônima no caso de success ainda não foi instanciada, porém nada impede que você chame `notificarNMsg()`.

Comment: Não entendi '-'

Comment: @RomarioPires volto daqui a pouco e continuo a explicação =)

Comment: Onde está location.href subestitua pela função que pretende criar após a pagina carregada (acionarAlerta(caminho)). Deve ficar como pretendido.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode escutar o evento de carga da `window`, após isso esperar um tempo (utilizando a função `setTimeout`) e então chamar a sua função.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        acionarAlerta("seu_caminho");
    }, 5000);
});
```

ou

```
window.onload = function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        acionarAlerta("seu_caminho");
    }, 5000);
});
```